# Deploying spring application in wildfly 11 result in " Only one AsyncAnnotationBeanPostProcessor may exist within the context." error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jboss, wildfly

We have a Java Spring 3.2 project, we are trying to migrate the project from jBoss 7 to wildFly 11

However, during the deployment the following error occurs:

> Cannot upload deployment: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./faultmanager" => 
>       "java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem:
>       Only one AsyncAnnotationBeanPostProcessor may exist within the context. Offending resource: 
>       \"/D:/wildfly-11.0.0.Final/wildfly-11.0.0.Final/bin/content/xxxx.war/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml\" 
>       Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: 
>       Configuration problem: Only one AsyncAnnotationBeanPostProcessor may exist within the context. Offending resource: 
>       \"/D:/wildfly-11.0.0.Final/wildfly-11.0.0.Final/bin/content/xxxxxx.war/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml\" 
>       Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: 
>       Only one AsyncAnnotationBeanPostProcessor may exist within the context. Offending resource: 
>       \"/D:/wildfly-11.0.0.Final/wildfly-11.0.0.Final/bin/content/xxxxxx.war/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml\""}}

With our attempts and our searches, we got that the exception could be throwed by some causes:

- Some bean in applicationContext.xml is defined twice
- The applicationContext.xml is imported twice
- Some bean defined in applcationContext.xml is defined again in a different file
- This may be caused by a  tag defined in applicationElement.xml, but trying to remove it will cause a illegalArgumentException during the deploy (don't know why), interestingly this doesn't appear to be used anywhere
- This may be caused by another contextl (we have an applicationContext-security) but even removing it the same error above will persist

Others fun facts:

- The error is never throwned during the build, only during the deploy throught wildFly
- The same project have worked for year in jboss without this kind of problem

What could be the cause?

Answer (score 0):

this will happens only ,

1)may be you are import both `applicationContext-root.xml` and `applicationContext-where-annotation-driven-is-specififed.xml` in your `WEB.xml` in  section.

2)make `applicationContext-root.xml` in `WEB.xml`.

2)This is happenning because you are initializ The application context twice but `org.springframework.scheduling.config.AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser` fails registering bean `ASYNC_ANNOTATION_PROCESSOR_BEAN_NAME` second time.

3)and spring parses the `<task:annotation-driven/>` text twice in a config XML.

may be one of the resons is that  `@ContextConfiguration("/path/to/applicationContext.xml")` are both the parent test class and child test class